# Problems when images need to upload

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

Good Day to all

I have a problem with my php and mysql. Everything worked fine till I added new things to my database and now my images give me errors when I click on create.

Below is the errors I am getting:

> Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\wamp\www\SA-Property
>   Finder\create.php on line 140
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on a non-object
>   in C:\wamp\www\SA-Property Finder\create.php on line 140

And here is my code:

```
//START IMAGES

        // insert data
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();


            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO properties (title,description,area,map,status,type,bedrooms,bathrooms,parking,garage,garden,pool,price,pets,agentnum,agentemail) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($title,$description,$area,$map,$status,$type,$bedrooms,$bathrooms,$parking,$garage,$garden,$pool,$price,$pets,$agentnum,$agentemail));
            Database::disconnect();

        }
       **$last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();**
       $directory="uploads/";
       $directoryagents="agents/";
$a=0;

foreach ($_FILES['agentfile']['name'] as $nameFile) {
            $ext = pathinfo($nameFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['agentfile']['tmp_name'][$a]))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['agentfile']['tmp_name'][$a], $directoryagents.$last_id."_".$a.".".$ext);
            }
            $fileandpath = $directoryagents.$last_id."_".$a.".".$ext;

            $pdo1 = Database::connect();
            $pdo1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql1 = "UPDATE properties SET agentimageurl=? WHERE PropertyId=?";
            $q1 = $pdo1->prepare($sql1);
            $q1->execute(array($fileandpath,$last_id));
            Database::disconnect();
        }


foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $nameFile) {


        $ext = pathinfo($nameFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$a]))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$a], $directory.$last_id."_".$a.".".$ext);
            }
            $fileandpath = $directory.$last_id."_".$a.".".$ext;

            $pdo1 = Database::connect();
            $pdo1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql1 = "INSERT INTO images (propertyid,imageurl) values(?, ?)";
            $q1 = $pdo1->prepare($sql1);
            $q1->execute(array( $last_id,$fileandpath));
            Database::disconnect();
            $a++;

        }
          header("Location: admin_list.php");
      }
```

This is line 140:

```
   $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

I just don't understand it worked fine, can't seem to see where my problem is.

Comment: I believe that problem is that when $valid is not true, you create no $pdo object, therefore you cannot use that method.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So what method should I use? I am kinda new to all this hahah still learning

Comment: I added an answer. I suggest you to avoid creating different PDO objects and connecting/disconnecting multiple times if you have to do several operations.

Comment: But how to I get it then to load separately?

Comment: You should replace your procedural code with OOP code, but it is not that simple if you just started with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Since the object $pdo doesn't exist outside of $valid context, my suggestion is to remove the creation of the object from inside the is($valid) check.

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
// insert data
if ($valid) {
        //$pdo = Database::connect();


        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        ...


}
```

And you should do the same with

```
Database::disconnect();
```

putting  it after the if check.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response, well its not giving me errors anymore but it doesn't show in my listings when i click on create.

Comment: What do you mean by "listings"?

Comment: Look I create a property for real estate agents, so after I fill in all the info of the property and then i click on create then in the admin panel it should show my listings i have created, but the problem isn't in there the problem is in the creating, at line 140

Comment: What does $last_id hold? Debug it. Debug all your code step by step, otherwise there will be questions one after the other in almost every line :) I simply answered what you asked, the undefined variable and call to non-object :)